# How to display animating countdown in confirmation box in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

All I wanna be able to do is to change the confirm message after its being displayed.

In this particular example I wanna give a 10 second time frame to the user to decide whether to do something or cancel it. So upon the display of the confirm popup then start counting down 10, 9 , 8 , ... 0 and once the time elapsed it continues the execution with the "do something" part (as if ok button was pressed)

Is it possible to implement such a thing with pure javascript or I have to libraries for that?

I am not looking for anything fancy though.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this with the normal `confirm`. With `confirm`, the program execution waits until the user selects OK or Cancel.

Instead, you will have to generate that confirmation box yourself (or with a JS library).